# Using Flask-User with app factory and blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I am working on my first bigger Flask App and having a few hang-ups with my project structure.

My App has the usual `models.py, routes.py` and `forms.py`. In the base folder I have `my_app.py` which imports `create_app` from `app`. I organized `routes.py` and `forms.py` inside a blueprint and register that blueprint in `create_app()` inside `__init__.py`.

As I have multiple roles, I am using `Flask-User` and need a `UserManager` object. To instanciate it, I need the app, db and user. Because `routes.py` is a blueprint which is registered with the app I tried to instanciate `Usermanager` with the blueprint. Gets me a Type Error.
Where do I instanciate the UserManager, where I also have the User model or how do I get my instance of `app` inside a module?

**EDIT:** I have found that there is `current_user` for my problem stated above.

Another hickup I have is in `forms.py`. I am generating one form with data from the db. When I do the `Questions.query.all()` I get a `RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.` 
What am I doing wrong there?

I even get that error inside the `create_all()` function when I try

```
from app import models
db.create_all()
```

.

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── admin
│       │   └── index.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── index.html
├── config.py
├── my_app.py
```

`init.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_user import UserManager
from flask_babelex import Babel

db = SQLAlchemy()
login = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

from app import models

# Setup Flask-User and specify the User data-model
user_manager = UserManager(app, db, models.User)
```

`routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from app.main.forms import LoginForm, QuestionForm, SurveyForm, TokenForm
from app.models import Question, Answer, User
from app.main import bp
from app.models import db
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user
from flask_user import current_user, login_required, roles_required, UserManager, UserMixin

# Setup Flask-User and specify the User data-model
user_manager = UserManager(bp, db, User)

@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/index')
@roles_required('Admin')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`forms.py`

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import $Fields...
from app.models import Question
from app import db

def getQuestions():
    '''Get questions from db to generate forms'''
    questions = Question.query.all()
```